# asking for number of players then asking for the names of each of those players?

Tags: python-3.x

Im creating a game that asks for the number of players then asking for the names of each player

i have tried to use %s to add players names but it ends up just adding one player

```
 players_dict = {}

 numPlayers = int(input("how many players are in the game?: ")

 for i in range(0,numPlayers):
     name = input("Enter player name: ")
     name = name.upper()
     players_dict.append(name)
```

error messages:
unused variable i

instance of dict has no append member

Comment: dictionaries are key value pairs. You can not simply "append" a single thing to them. Either turn your dict into a list or figure out what the second member of the pair is, then you can read about adding to a dict here : https://www.journaldev.com/23232/python-add-to-dictionary

Answer (score 0):

You can't append to a dictionary, try using a list instead:

```
players_dict = []

numPlayers = int(input("how many players are in the game?: ")

for i in range(0,numPlayers):
    name = input("Enter player name: ")
    name = name.upper()
    players_dict.append(name)
```

If you want to carry on using a dictionary then create keys instead:

```
players_dict = {}

numPlayers = int(input("how many players are in the game?: ")

for i in range(0,numPlayers):
    name = input("Enter player name: ")
    players_dict['player {}'.format(i)] = name.upper()
```

You can then access a player's name from the dict by their number:

```
players_dict['player 0']
players_dict['player 1']
```